# rstudio calls fortran subroutines - undefined symbol error

Tags: fortran, rstudio, gfortran

My apologies if this is a simple question for some people but I can't find the solution anywhere.
I am an RStudio beginner and I want to call specific routines of an open source fortran77 simulation program (there is also c and c++ code in it) from within RStudio. 
The Fortran program is using Makefiles for compiling and it generates many .o object files (by the way, I am using Unix). I wrote a wrapper file in fortran which compiles together with the simulation program and it is supposed to be used by RStudio for calling the fortran routines. I generate the shared object file .so of that wrapper file and all works well if I have simple calculations in that wrapper file. I am following the same process as in this excellent post:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/fortran-and-r-speed-things-up/

I use dyn.load and .Fortran successfully and I get results back as long as I do not call subroutines that are located in another file (and correspond to other object files and other .so files). When I try to call another subroutine from within the wrapper subroutine I get the following error:

```
Error in dyn.load("rwrapper.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/adminuser/ESP-rSource/src/esrubps/rwrapper.so':
  /home/adminuser/ESP-rSource/src/esrubps/rwrapper.so: undefined symbol: runit_
```

runit (without underscore) is another subroutine that is located in another file and has another object file. I then tried to make a second shared object file for that runit subroutine and I also load it with dyn.load but it did not fix the problem. I am probably doing something wrong here but I do not know what. Do I need to convert all object files to .so shared object files and then use dyn.load to load each one of them (there are around 100 of .o files) or would the "wrapper/communication" file approach work? Is there a way to establish communication between the fortran program and RStudio? I am pasting my RStudio script here for information only (note that the 2nd dyn.load does not make a difference):

```
myrwrapper <- function(rrrandom) {
  if (!is.loaded('rwrapper')) {
    dyn.load("rwrapper.so")
  }
  if (!is.loaded('esru_lib')) {
    dyn.load("./home/adminuser/ESP-rSource/src/lib/esru_lib.so")
  }
  retvals <- .Fortran("RXCHNGE",icomp = as.integer(2), rCOUPLEVAR = as.numeric(rrrandom))
  return(retvals$rCOUPLEVAR)
}
```

An easy solution would have been to write/read a text file from both programs and exchange data through that file, however my understanding is that this would make the simulations really slow because of the need to open/close a file at almost every time step, and so I am trying to avoid such an approach.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since there is no response yet, I should try and simplify what I say above. 
1. I use RStudio (dyn.load and .Fortran) to call a fortran routine. 
2. When the fortran routine has simple internal calculations I receive back in RStudio a valid answer
3. When the fortran routine has a call to another subroutine in ANOTHER file, the whole thing fails and RStudio gives a message saying that the name of that subroutine is an undefined symbol. It also places an underscore “_” after the name of the subroutine. Calling another subroutine within the same file seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a lot easier than I thought. It was a novice mistake with the shared .so file. Problem solved when creating the shared file and linking it to two (or more) object files rather than one. For example if you have 1.F which calls 2.F and the respective 1.o and 2.o, you should include both files when creating the shared file as:
    gfortran -shared -o 1plus2.so 1.o 2.o